# cl.exe: LNK1104: cannot open file - and I'm not even telling it to link

Tags: visual-c++

I am compiling several C++ sources using `cl.exe` (Visual Studio 2010 Express). The sources are compiling fine and it generates the respective `obj` files, but after the last line of "Generating code..." it throws the infamous `LNK1104` error, but of the weirdest kind I have ever seen:

```
Generating Code...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Color.exe'
```

Now, `Color.exe` does not exist, I do not want it to exist, I am not telling cl to create it, neither do I even tell it to link at all, I only want to compile. `Color.obj` happens to be the first output file of the compiler (alphabetical order), so I assume this problem is kinda linked to it.

The command line of my `cl.exe` invocation looks like follows (I trimmed the includes, they aren't part of the problem):

```
cl /nologo /Ox /EHsc /I[...] "D:\Projects\Java\JSFML\src\cpp\Intercom\*.cpp" "D:\Projects\Java\JSFML\src\cpp\JNI\*.cpp" /FoD:\Projects\Java\JSFML\out\obj\
```

The working directory is the MS Visual Studio directory. I assume that it cannot "open" `Color.exe` because it cannot write in that directory. However, my question is: why would `cl` even want to create it? I'm not telling it to link?

Comment: Try adding a /c to your compile, means "compile, don't link".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default of most (if not all) C/C++ compilers is to perform the linking step unless you explicitly tell them not to.

If you take a look at [this page](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/clexe-cmd-line-args.html) which covers "cl.exe", you'll find an option, `/c` (compile only, no link) that will turn that behavior off for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling it to link.  If you don't want to link, use the `/c` option (for compile-only).